# SUM IF with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sum

I have query that is making summary of some qunatities in table according to some condition.

This is how my query looks:

```
SELECT products.code AS Code, products.IDCustomer, 
SUM(IF(production.progress <> 7, (production.QTY),0)) AS TotQTY, 
production.Code, production.IDCustomer, production.Progress, 
production.MainIDProduction, production.KITDate
FROM products
LEFT JOIN production ON products.Code = production.Code
WHERE products.Active = 1 AND products.IDCustomer = 8
GROUP BY production.Code, products.Code
```

There is criteria for summary to make sum ofall qty for products which have progress different that 7. Now I need to modify query to execlude products which have progress 7 and 11.

What is best approch for that?

Comment: just put an OR in your IF

Comment: You can use the same logical operators within your if() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `NOT IN` condition in `WHERE` clause and calculate the `SUM`, e.g.:

```
SELECT products.code AS Code, products.IDCustomer, 
SUM(production.QTY) AS TotQTY, 
production.Code, production.IDCustomer, production.Progress, 
production.MainIDProduction, production.KITDate
FROM products
LEFT JOIN production ON products.Code = production.Code
WHERE products.Active = 1 AND products.IDCustomer = 8
AND production.progress NOT IN (7, 11)
GROUP BY production.Code, products.Code
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to insert '`and`' condition

```
    SELECT products.code AS Code, products.IDCustomer, 
    SUM(IF(production.progress <> 7 and production.progress <> 11, (production.QTY),0)) AS TotQTY, 
    production.Code, production.IDCustomer, production.Progress, 
    production.MainIDProduction, production.KITDate
    FROM products
    LEFT JOIN production ON products.Code = production.Code
    WHERE products.Active = 1 AND products.IDCustomer = 8
    GROUP BY production.Code, products.Code
```